# Python numpy sigmoid function returns numbers greater than 1

Tags: python, numpy, sigmoid

I guess I am missing something pretty trivial, but don't know what.

Sigmoid function must always return values between 0 and 1, right? My sigmoid function is implemented properly, right? I am providing -70 and expecting something close to 0, but get 3.9.

I just can't figure out what is going on. I've attached an image showing the behavior. np is numpy.

[image]

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E_notation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `e[some integer]` means power of tens. So for example, `1e10` means 1* 10^(10). Hence, the value is 3.9 * 10^(-31), not 3.9, which is correct .

Comment: Ooops, knew it was something pretty obvious. I had to pay more attention than troubleshoot for hours. Anyway gotta learn something new each day. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Basically, it is correct answer. the "e-31" means `10^(-31)`. So the answer is actually close to:

```
0.000000000000000000000000000003975449735908647
```

which is *very* close to 0.